# Keep only the Restart button in the start menu of Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, batch

In the start menu there are 6 buttons, `Shutdown`, `Restart`, `Logoff`, `Switch User`, `Lock` and `Hibernate`, I want remove them all but only keep the `Restart` button.

I've done some research and found some useful commands.

Remove `Shutdown`, `Restart` and `Hibernate`,

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer" /v "NoClose" /d 1 /t REG_DWORD /f
```

Disable the `Logoff` button, you can see it but it becomes grey,

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer" /v "StartMenuLogOff" /d 1 /t REG_DWORD /f
```

Disable the `Switch User` button,

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" /v "HideFastUserSwitching" /d 1 /t REG_DWORD /f
```

Disable the `Switch User` and `Lock` buttons,

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" /v "DisableLockWorkstation" /d 1 /t REG_DWORD /f
```

But I haven't found any combination that can remove all the other 5 buttons but keep only the `Restart` button.

Any ideas ? Thanks!

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/7553/remove-shutdown-and-restart-buttons-in-windows-7/

Comment: Are you trying to just prevent inadvertent pressing of the wrong option such as shutdown? You could disable ALL the options and make the end user click on a desktop or start menu shortcut to restart so they have to make a conscience decision to press the one and one option which could be named "Restart" and just be a command line of `SHUTDOWN /F /R /T 01`  for example. Why remove logoff though, is there some problem caused by the end-user logging off or are you just trying to get the device power cycled per each end-user being done for the day or whatever?

Comment: My case here is a little special, I want to keep only the restart button in the start menu